# FCKEDITOR table insertion problem from doc

Tags: fckeditor

When i copy paste table from word file, it doesn't allow me to add text outside the table.
I follow this procedure
1)copy paste the table from Microsoft word file using "paste word" option in fckeditor.
But after that, if i want to type some text outside the table , fckeditor doesn't allow me to do so.

the cursor doesn't go outside of table

thanks for any help, solutions in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somehow managed to fix this bug. patchwork :P

\editor\dialog\fck_paste.html
line no 100 inside   function Ok(){}

added some lines at two places

1)

```
else 
    sHtml = oBody.innerHTML ;
// 25oct2010 added to fix After pasting a table from word it is not possible to navigate outside the table
    if ( oEditor.FCKBrowserInfo.IsIE )
        sHtml+="";
    else
        sHtml+="< br / >";
    //end  25oct2010 added to fix After pasting a table from word it is not possible to navigate outside the table 
        // Fix relative anchor URLs (IE automatically adds the current page URL).
        var re = new RegExp( window.location + "#", "g" ) ;
```

2)

```
range.MoveToBookmark( bookmark ) ;
        range.Collapse( false ) ;
        range.Select() ;
        range.Release() ;
        return true ;
    }
    // 25oct2010 added to fix After pasting a table from word it is not possible to navigate outside the table
    if ( oEditor.FCKBrowserInfo.IsIE )
        sHtml+="";
    else
        sHtml+="< br / >";
    //end  25oct2010 added to fix After pasting a table from word it is not possible to navigate outside the table
    oEditor.FCK.InsertHtml( sHtml ) ;
```

Note: make the br tag proper at these lines sHtml+="< br / >";